# Using sed to delete a Variable

Tags: linux, sed

I am trying to use `sed` to delete a line which contains the variable `$filegrep`:

```
filename=$(basename "$1")
filegrep=$(grep "$filename" /home/$USER/Desktop/Trash/Index/Index.txt)
filefir=$(dirname "filegrep")
```

I am attempting to do it with this command:

```
sed -i '/$filegrep/d' /home/$USER/Desktop/Trash/Index/Index.txt
```

However, I receive the error

```
sed: no input files
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  Note that it is worth spending time to get things spelled correctly.  It is clear that `fielgrep`, `filegrep-$(...)`, `unput` are typos; I suspect `filefir` is one too (more likely intended to be `filedir`); and it's likely that the line should be `filedir=$(dirname "$filegrep")`.  Please read up on how to create an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).

Answer (score 1):

Strings in `'`-quoted vars don't expand variables:

```
marc@panic:~$ touch test.txt
marc@panic:~$ X=test.txt
marc@panic:~$ ls '$X'    <---single-quoted
ls: cannot access $X: No such file or directory
marc@panic:~$ ls "$X"    <---double-quoted
test.txt
```

Change your quotes in the sed call to `"`:

```
sed -i "/$filegrep/d" /home/$USER/Desktop/Trash/Index/Index.txt
       ^--          ^--
```